# Mat-option values based on a condition

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am just trying to populate values in a mat-select.

```
 <mat-select id="selproj" class="proj-selector" >
      <mat-option *ngFor="let project of projects " [value]="project.projId">
        {{project.projName}}
      </mat-option>
 </mat-select>
```

The project array is something like this

```
0: {projStatus: "Y", projName: "Test-1", projtId: 3}
1: {projStatus: "N", projName: "Test-2", projId: 9}
```

Now what I am looking to do is if the projstatus is no , I have to show mat-option value in the select box as projname-notactive. But if the project status is Y, I should show only the project name.  I cannot use both ngif and ngfor together in mat-option. How can I acheive this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use `ng-container` for `*ngFor` and use *ngIf on `mat-option`

```
 <mat-select id="selproj" class="proj-selector" >
    <ng-container *ngFor="let project of projects ">
      <mat-option *ngIf="condition" [value]="project.projId">
        {{project.projName}}
      </mat-option>
    </ng-container>
 </mat-select>
```

Replace `condition` with whatever condition you need.

Hope it helps!

**EDIT:**

With the condition stated in the comment, you need not use `ng-container`. You can use `*ngIf` in span

```
<mat-option [value]="project.projId">
  {{project.projName}} <span *ngIf="project.projStatus=='N'">Not-Active</span>
</mat-option>
```

And if you only need text in `mat-option` ...

```
<mat-option [value]="project.projId">
  {{project.projName + (project.projStatus=='N' ? 'Not-Active' : '')}}
</mat-option>
```

Comment: Sorry I have updated my question. I have two condition. <mat-option *ngIf="project.projstatus=='N" [value]="project.projId">
        {{project.projName}}+"Not-Active" and if status is Y then only project name. How can I write that.
      </mat-option>

Comment: Not sure how to append a text with projname.

Comment: Check Edit now.

Comment: Added another option for you

Comment: you may need to use brackets.. I'll edit the answer

Comment: Yes the bracket worked. Would like to know which one is standard?

Comment: Can use any one as need be. If you need to style 'Not-Active' differently, then using in `span` would be better

Comment: Ok. Thanks for your help and support.